# move three symbols & text to left side

Tags: html, css

if you see top right [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/human-skulls-and-bones-apple-iphone-4s-phone-case.html) , we can see 3 symbols and currency text ,

[image]

i want to move **three symbols & text to left side.**

```
.skip-searchs span.icon {
    background-position: 8px -150px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.header-minicart .icon, .skip-cart:not(.skip-active):hover .icon {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Can you explain more?

Comment: @ketan
 below drop-down you can see white line right, i want to display dropdown options align to that line

Comment: you can see here : http://prntscr.com/bvk2fr , INR text is not aligned to line present in below , vertically i want to display in same place

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ketan please check updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Three symbol and text** is your `logo`, so if you want to move that to `left` then add this changes into your codes.

```
.logo .small {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
    left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: i addded your code, but it didt worked for me, please check.

Comment: I could not see your updated CSS codes. Replace your code with above html img tag code.

Comment: i added in external css, not sure why its not reflecting.

Comment: i added the code on top of the css file, can you please tell me what file name and in what line i have to add the code

Comment: i tried both your solutions, by html and through css, please check here : http://prnt.sc/bvmv4j

Comment: @USer345738380 In your CSS stylesheet make that changes, don't just add that code. First find that line of code and then make changes in styles.css

Comment: i added the code in top of the css file. also i added in particular class also in extrenal css, still it not working for me

Comment: can you please check above image, code is reflecting, but still not working for me

Comment: @USer345738380 yes on that line change that to -20px, I could see difference, you can change it's value as much as you want. It will move towards left.

Comment: yes, when i chnage values, logo is moving, but i want to move the 3 symbols and text present on right side.